# How to fetch two different commits of the same project to different local folders using GIT

Tags: git, git-clone

I am new to Git so please bear with me. I am trying to grab two different commits of a same project, specifically a current commit and an old commit with certain hash. I want them to clone it in separate folders (so that they don't overwrite and I can open them as separate projects at same time)? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a clone copies all of a repository's history, so you can just copy the repo and check out the other branch/commit in one of them. For example:

```
git clone ssh://someserver/repo
cp repo repo2
cd repo
git checkout HASH1
cd ../repo2
git checkout HASH2
```

Comment: I'd recommend cloning repo to repo2 (`git clone repo repo2`), so that git can hard-link all the pack files.